# error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl v0.9.24`

Tags: rust, installation, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I want to install cargo-apk `cargo install cargo-apk` to my system (Linux Mint), but I'm getting this error

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl v0.9.24`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-install7N44TO/release/build/openssl-65bb03053b1fc095/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to detect OpenSSL version', /home/jiri/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.9.24/build.rs:16:14
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `cargo-apk v0.4.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install7N44TO`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

I found that I should install libssl-dev, so I did, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

rust openssl-sys library needs openssl installed.

then on Windows :
download and install it from here first :
http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

```
then set this EnvironmentVariable:
```

> set OPENSSL_DIR=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\

on linux :

> sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev

or

> sudo pacman -S openssl

or

> sudo dnf install openssl-devel

or

> curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0f.tar.gz tar xf

> openssl-1.1.0f.tar.gz cd openssl-1.1.0f export CC=... ./Configure

> --prefix=... linux-x86_64 -fPIC make -j$(nproc) make install

and in osx just :

> xcode-select --install

> brew install openssl

Comment: i already have openssl installed and still got this build error

Comment: @alexzander what is your os? is openssl in your PATH?

Comment: so do i need to put the `/usr/bin/openssl` into `$PATH` ? that should fix the issue ?

Comment: @alexzander you should give it a try, i think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in Windows. Steps I did to resolve the issue.

1. Install cygwin - https://www.cygwin.com/
2. Install perl(from cygwin bash terminal) - https://learn.perl.org/installing/windows.html
3. Then tried cargo install from cygwin bash terminal.